# Is it possible to define an XML schema with an arbitrary number of elements?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema, sequence

Here is my code so far and my question is how do I define elements within the sequence?
(Each element in the sequence is also required to have attributes "name" and "Position")

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xs:element name="FieldData">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="1stElement" position="">
             ...
            <xs:element name="nthElement" position="">
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Comment: I suggest you to look at [this simple XML Schema tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/schema/). As you will see, you can do what you want easily ussing *xs:attribute*.

Comment: If you are saying that you don't care what the name of the element is, so long as it has the right attributes, then that's not something you can do in XSD 1.0. But I'm guessing wildly here, you need to be much more clear in your question.

Comment: Yeah so I don't care about what the name of each element is so long as the rest of the attributes are consistent. All I want is to be able to define an arbitrary number of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to define an arbitrary number of elements within a sequence.  Here's one simple way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:element name="FieldData">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="e1" type="eType"/>
        <xs:element name="e2" type="eType"/>
        <xs:element name="e3" type="eType"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <xs:complexType name="eType">
    <xs:attribute name="name" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute name="Position" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>

</xs:schema>
```

If this does not meet your needs, please provide more details.

Comment: Just curious does using the <xs:any> tag also suffice?

Comment: Yes, but then you won't be able to require specific attributes, at least not with XSD 1.0.